# Product of signs of two juxtaposition of two disjoint permutations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, permutation-cycles

**Edited:** Suppose we are given two disjoint permutations $(a_1,\dots,a_m)$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$. I want to prove that (if it is correct)

$$\text{sgn}(a_1,\dots,a_m, b_1,\dots,b_n)\times \text{sgn}(b_1,\dots,b_n, a_1,\dots,a_m)=(-1)^{\sum_{i=1}^m (a_i-1)+\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-1)}.$$

Where $\text{sgn}$ denotes the sign of permutation which is $+1$ or $-1$ depending on whether the permutation is even or
odd.
 <s>I know that parity of a $k$-cycle is $k-1$. I think $(a_1,\dots,a_m, b_1,\dots,b_n)$ is same as $(a_1,\dots,a_m)(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ because they are disjoint cycles, so $\text{sgn}(a_1,\dots,a_m, b_1,\dots,b_n)=\text{sgn}(a_1,\dots,a_m)\cdot\text{sgn}(b_1,\dots,b_n)$. Right? And $\text{sgn}(a_1,\dots,a_m)=(-1)^{m-1}$ and $\text{sgn}(b_1,\dots,b_n)=(-1)^{n-1}$ But these seems do not imply the above claim.</s>

Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you define sgn of permutations? And what is the permutation $(a_1,\dots,a_m, b_1,\dots,b_n)$; not the product of the cycles ?

Comment: When the book writes $\text{sgn}(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_r, j_1, j_2, \dots, j_{n-r})$ I suspect it means the sign of the permutation taking $1\mapsto i_1$, $2\mapsto i_2$, ..., $n\mapsto j_{n-r}$, and has nothing to do with cycles.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: Thanks for comment. In this case do you know how to prove the claim?

Comment: I deleted a silly comment I made last night.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: So the problem is not so easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I think from looking
[at the page of the book you reference](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PQ0tHdtC3QwC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA291&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)
in a comment to the answer by Henno Brandsma (which answers the question you originally posed) that what is meant here by $\text{sgn}(c_1,c_2,\dots, c_N)$ is the sign of the permutation $i\mapsto c_i$.

What you are looking at is the case where $N=m+n$, and the first $m$ $c_i$ are  $c_i=a_i$ and the last $n$ $c_i$ are $c_{i-m}=b_i$.

When you look at
$$
\text{sgn}(a_1,\dots,a_m, b_1,\dots,b_n)\times \text{sgn}(b_1,\dots,b_n, a_1,\dots,a_m)
$$
you might as well ask for
$$
\text{sgn}(a_1,\dots,a_m, b_1,\dots,b_n)^{-1}\times \text{sgn}(b_1,\dots,b_n, a_1,\dots,a_m)
$$
since for every permutation $\pi$ we know that $\pi^1$ and $\pi$ have the same sign.

We also know that for any pair of permutations $\pi_1,\pi_2$ the sign of $\pi_1\pi_2$ is just the product of the signs of $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$. So what you really want to calculate is
$$
\text{sgn}(a_1,\dots,a_m, b_1,\dots,b_n)^{-1}
(b_1,\dots,b_n, a_1,\dots,a_m).
$$

But what is this permutation? It is the permutation taking $a_1$ to $1$ to $b_1$, $a_2$ to $2$ to $b_2$, ..., $b_n$ to $n$ to $a_m$.  [To avoid confusion I read my permutations left to right.]

So how many swaps does it take to move the $a_i$ behind the $b_i$? Well each of the $m$ $a_i$ must slip past $n$ of the $b_j$, so that there are $mn$ swaps.

Hence the sign of the permutation is $(-1)^{mn}$ or if you prefer $(-1)^{m(N-m)}$; the latter is the form given in "Solution (2)" of your book.

**Edit: Further question in the comments below.**

You are asking (I think) where one of the intermediate formulas in Solution(2) of the book comes from. At this stage we are trying to compute the sign of the permutation $(a_1,a_2,\dots, a_m,b_1,\dots, b_n)$ where this notation still means the permutation taking $1\dots (m+n)$ to these values.

I believe that in the book we have this added information: $a_1<a_2<\dots<a_m$ and $b_1<b_2<\dots<b_n$. To calculate the sign of this permutation note that we have to first swap the first $(a_1-1)$ elements $b_j$ past the $m$ elements $a_i$. Next we have to swap the next $(a_2-a_1-1)$ elements $b_j$ past  $(m-1)$ elements $a_i$. Next we have to swap the next $(a_3-a_2-1)$ elements $b_j$ past  $(m-2)$ elements $a_i$. And so on. When I calculate this sum and simplify it I get -f I have made no mistake-  $\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_i - {m\choose 2}$ which is what is required in the book.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My confusing point is that I want to rearrange the above perm to the identity perm any way. But I don't know really where $1$ is mapped and $2$ and so on.

Comment: If you look at the book, Solution (2) uses a sum formula that I do not know where it came from?

Comment: It doesn't matter where it came from, $N(N-m)$ clearly  has the same parity as enormous sum in question. But I think you ought to be able to prove it by counting swaps in the same sort of way.

Comment: I really think that you need to say what it is exactly that you want to prove. The original question is now clearly in need of a massive edit explaining that permutations are not being written in cycle form but ... and the reference to the book shouldn't be buried in a comment which is usually hidden.

Comment: At the line "It is the permutation taking ..." I think it is somehow vague. because we don't know that whether $m>n$ or $n>m$!

Comment: Also, Your last line remark is not correct. $\sum_{i=1}^m (a_i-1)+\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-1)= \sum a_i+\sum b_j -(m(m+1)/2+n(n+1)/2)=(m+n)(m+n+1)/2-(m(m+1)/2+n(n+1)/2)=mn/2+mn/2=mn.$

Comment: I've corrected the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter exactly how the $a_i$ and $b_i$ line up, the count of swaps is correct.

Comment: I have tried to address your 2nd comment in my edit.

Comment: I am pretty sure that $a_1<a_2<\dots<a_m$ is not a part of assumption. Your answer is fine but the book argument confused me.

Comment: In the third line of Solution(1) the book explicitly makes that assumption, and Solution (2) flows on as far as I can see. After all we're just interested in the canonical generators.

Answer (score 0):

$\text{sgn}((a_1,\cdots,a_m)) = (-1)^{m-1}$ indeed.

Also, by disjointness $(a_1,\cdots,a_m)(b_1,\cdots,b_n) = (b_1,\cdots,b_n) (a_1,\cdots,a_m)$. So the product of their signs is $(-1)^{m-1} (-1)^{n-1} = (-1)^{m+n-2}$.

I don't know what you mean by $\text{sgn}(a_1,\dots,a_m, b_1,\dots,b_n)$ though. Is that the combined cycle? But this is not the same as the product.. In either order this new cycle has sign $(-1)^{m+n-1}$, being of length $m+n$..

Comment: What do you meant by  combined cycle? they are disjoint so I don't think make difference.

Comment: @C.F.G If we have the cycles $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6)$ in $S_7$, $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ is different from $(4,5,6,1,2,3)$ as permutations. and different again from $(1,2,3)(4,5,6)$, their product.

Comment: Aha, Probably my post is about $(1,2,3),(4,5,6)\to (1,2,3,4,5,6)$ I think. (as I noted " juxtaposition").

Comment: In the juxtaposition we have one cycle so the sign is clear: $(-1)^{m+n-1}$ (in either order), still not equal to the product which is the sign of the product.

Comment: @C.F.G $(a_1,\dots,a_m, b_1,\dots,b_n) \times (b_1,\dots,b_n, a_1,\dots,a_m)$ has sign $+1$ always.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand my question. [see (2) of this page (291) for clarification](https://books.google.com/books?id=PQ0tHdtC3QwC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA291#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Actually $sgn$ appear in $\star a_1\wedge \dots \wedge a_k=sgn a_{k+1}\wedge \dots \wedge a_n$. where star is the Hodge star operator.

Comment: @C.F.G See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator), maybe it helps?

Comment: Thanks but I have seen it before and was not helpful.